# Attributes sorting issue

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute

I have size attribute (S,M,L,XL,2XL).
I want to sort it by this way, now its showing like (2XL,S,M,L,XL).
How can I sort it?
I am using following code:

```
$products_grid_ret = array();
$temparray = array();
foreach($products_grid as $key => $product) {
  $temparray[$key] = array();
  foreach($product['attributes'] as $att) {
    $temparray[$key][] = $att['value'];
  }
}
$sorted_array = $temparray;
sort($sorted_array);
foreach($sorted_array as $atts) {
  $key = array_search($atts, $temparray);
  $products_grid_ret[$key] = $products_grid[$key];
}
return $products_grid_ret;
```

Comment: I solved it myself....

Comment: If you have time - put your solution here. Can be helpful for another people.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($product['attributes'] as $att) {
    $temparray[$key][] = $att['option_id'];
}
```

Comment: did this fix the issue for you? then feel free to accept the answer